# 2D basic movement UNITY

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Currently my character works perfectly on the keyboard, but when I convert your movements to touch, through 3 UI Buttons (i tried UI image too, but success) i'm not succeeding

It basically goes to the right, left, and jumps.

How should do to make it follow these instructions:

When the user presses directional, the character does not stop walking until the user user releases the button, and when you press the jump player jump.

This is the script I use to move through the keyboard!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float velocity;

    public Transform player;
    private Animator animator;

    public bool isGrounded;
    public float force;

    public float jumpTime = 0.4f;
    public float jumpDelay = 0.4f;
    public bool jumped = false;
    public Transform ground;

    private Gerenciador gerenciador;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        gerenciador = FindObjectOfType (typeof(Gerenciador)) as Gerenciador;
        animator = player.GetComponent<Animator> ();
        gerenciador.StartGame ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

        Move ();

    }

    void Move ()
    {

        isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast (this.transform.position, ground.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Floor"));
        animator.SetFloat ("run", Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")));
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0) {

            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * velocity * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0) {

            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * velocity * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 180);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Vertical") && isGrounded && !jumped) {

            //  rigidbody2D.AddForce (transform.up * force);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (transform.up * force);
            jumpTime = jumpDelay;
            animator.SetTrigger ("jump");
            jumped = true;
        }

        jumpTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (jumpTime <= 0 && isGrounded && jumped) {

            animator.SetTrigger ("ground");
            jumped = false;

        }
    }
}
```

C# if possible, remember i am using Canvas UI for these buttons =]

Comment: Why dont you use touch input? Here you can find more details:  [Input.touches](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html).

Comment: implement IPointerDownHandler and IPointerUpHandler from UnityEngine.EventSystems (sounds worse than it is, there are plenty of tutorials for the event system)

Comment: You get voted down if you don't put code in your question when it is necessary. Glad you changed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Jump action, what you need is a Button. **GameObject->UI->Button**. Replace the Image with your own image and click "Set Native Size". Re-size the button to the size that's good for your game.

Attach the Button to the **Jump Button** slot script below.

```
public Button jumpButton;

void jumpButtonCallBack()
{
    //  rigidbody2D.AddForce (transform.up * force);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up * force);
    jumpTime = jumpDelay;
    animator.SetTrigger("jump");
    jumped = true;
}


void OnEnable(){
    //Un-Register Button
    jumpButton.onClick.AddListener(() => jumpButtonCallBack());
}

void OnDisable(){
    //Un-register Button
    jumpButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

For the **Left** and **Right** Movement buttons,you should **not** use `Button` component for them like the jump button. You have to implement **Virtual JoyStick** to make it look realistic. Unity have Assets called CrossPlatformInputManager that can do that. You have to import it and modify it a little bit in order to use it. Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGYObojmkO4) to understand how to import it.

Now, you can replace your `Input.GetAxis` and `Input.GetAxisRaw` functions with `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal")` and `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")`.

If you get it to work, then can use below to make your code comptible with both mobile and desktop.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_WEBGL
//put your Input.GetAxis` and `Input.GetAxisRaw` code here
#elif UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS 
//Put your `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal")` and `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")`. here
#endif
```

Comment: Another time u give me the best soo far away asnwer! Ty again =]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use EventTrigger OnPointerDown and OnPointerUp events:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html

I hope it helps you