# how can i implement first person controller movement touch keys for android devices in unity 4.5

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unityscript

i'm new to **Unity** . i have a simple Terrain in my unity project. **what is the simplest way to implement touch joystick buttons to my project so mobile users can move around with**?

something like this
[mobile movement joystick example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ6A5.png)

when i export my project for PC it works fine by keyboard keys but what about android/iPhone users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a **Virtual JoyStick**. Simply posting code here is not enough to get you started. Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGYObojmkO4) video, it shows how to make one from start to finish.

For more examples about moving the character, look at the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834622/2d-basic-movement-unity) question. The question contains code for moving the character with the keyboard and the answer explains how to move it with touch (**Virtual JoyStick**) on Android.

Comment: That Virtual Joy Stick "Save me" =] Ty again programmer

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have a built-in way to do this. Alternatively, you can take a look at the **[Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/)**, it's a great place to look for piece of codes, assets and stuff. 
For example you can use in your project these free assets: [CN Controls](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15233) , [Standalone Multi-Touch Input Module](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28861)